# MS Excel COM Issue - Unable to get the image out from Clipboard while using excel COM object

Tags: c#, excel, web, com, clipboard

Unable to get the image out from Clipboard while using excel COM object Range.CopyPicture method

On my local machine everything is working fine but on server I am facing this issue.
Local machine I have office 2016 installed and at server we have Excel-2013 installed.

After deployment when i run the web application then it is throwing exception (object ref not to set instance).
But when I go to server and manually doing ctrl+v (paste) in any word doc directly then it pasting the image there, But from the code it is not able to read the image.

Code-

```
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
     xlApp.CutCopyMode = XlCutCopyMode.xlCopy;
     Range range = xlWorkSheet.get_Range(startRange, endRange);                                              
     System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.Clear();               
                            
     range.CopyPicture(XlPictureAppearance.xlScreen, XlCopyPictureFormat.xlBitmap);
     
     //Here getting null in imgWS1                                     
     Image imgWS1 = System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetImage(); 
                              
     string fileName = Path.Combine(reportPath, imageName);

     //Getting exception- object ref not to set an instance..           
     imgWS1.Save(fileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Things I have tried
1.) When I am adding the test image in clipboard through

```
Forms.Clipboard.SetImage(imgtest);
```

then

```
Clipboard.GetImage()
```

is working fine. So here I think some problem is with the CopyPicture method.

2.) I also tried using DataObject but had no luck.

```
 System.Windows.Forms.DataObject o = Forms.Clipboard.GetDataObject() as DataObject;
 System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetImage(GetClipboardImage(o));
```